# Почему проверка на палиндром не работает?

Tags: javascript

Почему `rev === ["t", "o", "n"]` , а не `["n", "o", "t"]` ?

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  var rev = str.toLowerCase().split("");
  var rev1 = rev.reverse();
  console.log(rev);
  console.log(rev1);
  return rev1 === rev ? true : false;
  // Good luck!
}

palindrome("not");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще получить сразу реверсивную строку и сравнить с оригиналом

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  var lowerCaseString = str.toLowerCase();
  var reverseString = lowerCaseString.split("").reverse().join("");
  console.log(lowerCaseString);
  console.log(reverseString);
  return lowerCaseString === reverseString;
  // Good luck!
}

palindrome("not");
```

Comment: исправил код, т.к. сравниваются lowerCase строки

Answer (score 1):

Потому что [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) разворачивает оргинальный массив.
Вы разворачиваете rev, а потом копируете его в rev1.

И кстати вот эта конструкция лишняя - 
`return rev1 === rev ? true : false;`
достаточно будет `return rev1 === rev;`

Comment: там и `==` достаточно

Comment: там и return false достаточно , тк объект равен только самому себе. Можно rev1.join() === rev.join() сделать